# Lentitud ReportVIewer

Tags: sql, visual-studio, vb.net, reportviewer, visual

Al hacer RefreshReport al ReportViewer se queda pillado.

Os explico un poco:

Tengo varios proyectos del mismo tipo, que en conclusión su finalidad es crear un informe con los datos sacados de un bbdd. EL tema es que ultimamente cuando voy a generar el informe para visualizar en el ReportViewer se queda pillado el programa, ni responde.

Cuando depuro todos los pasos los hace correctamente exceptoel ultimo que es cuando uso :
`Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()`

A que se puede deber? Si reinicio el ordenador suele volver a funcionar almenos con uno o dos informes, pero después se vuelve a queda pillado.

Gracias.

Si necesitáis algo mas de código, decídmelo.

Answer (score 0):

No se a que se puede deber el problema, pero puedes probar a limpiar el origen de datos del **ReportViewer** cuando se invoca el método que presenta el reporte con la siguiente linea:

```
// Inicio del método
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

// Filan del método
this.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
```

El código mostrado es en C#, aunque en Visual Basic será muy parecido.

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: He probado lo que me has comentado pero en el report aparece:"No se ha proporcionado ninguna instancia de origen de datos para el origen de datos".

No se si tendrá algo que ver pero antes de mostrar el report con toda la información, muestro el mismo report pero solo con valores en el encabezado con datos generales, y luego a través de un botón al hacer click muestro todo lo demás.